# Пустая юникодная строка

Tags: python-2.x, unicode

В чужом коде увидел такое:

```
return u''
```

Пустая юникодная строка `u''` чем-то отличается от просто пустой строки `''`? Если да — чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в типе:

```
>>> u'' == ''
True
>>> type(u'') == type('')
False
>>> type(u'')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type('')
<type 'str'>
```

Хотя она довольно эфемерна:

```
>>> type(''  u'я')
<type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: Ну да, очевидно. :) А может быть код, который по-разному работает с этими двумя пустыми строками? Разумеется, кроме условий по типу объекта.

Comment: (минус не мой, кстати)

Comment: непонятно за что минус...